# I have done that before vs I have done that

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs, present-perfect

Is there a difference between "I have done that before" and "I have done that"?

I'm not sure if these sentences make sense:

> A: "**Have** you ever **done** this **before**?"
>
> B: "Yes, I **have done** that **before**."

and

> C: "**Have** you ever **lived** there **before**?"
>
> D: "Yes, I've lived there before."

If you want to imply that you have done something at some unspecified time in the past, is it correct to use "have done/lived before"? Is this construction possible? If it is possible, is there a difference between "have done/lived" and "have done/lived before"?

Should I just say "I did that before" and "I used to live there"? I want to convey that I have once done something in the past but doesn't necessarily mean that I'm still doing the doing/living. I just can't articulate my thoughts well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are correct. They can replace each other easily, and in the same conversation. If you want to stress that fact that you only did something once then throw 'once' in there. 
"Yes, I have done that once before." or "Yes, I've lived there once before."